# If the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of a function exists at a point $c$, then all prior derivatives exist (i.e. the $n-1$, $n-2$, ... $n-n$) at point $c$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Question 21 of Chapter 10 in Spivak's *Calculus* asks the reader to prove the following statement:

> If $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f \circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists.

I realized that in order to prove the above statement, I would need to prove the below lemma:

> For any $x \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 \lt x \leq n$, if $f^{(n)}(c)$ exists, then $f^{(n-x)}(c)$ exists. $\quad \dagger$

This post is about *this* ($\dagger$) lemma. I prove it by induction...but the manner in which I go about it struck me as a little odd (i.e. the approach I use is one that I have not used before, which makes me think that maybe I am being unnecessarily pedantic, and maybe this lemma can be proved another way.) If someone could confirm that the proof reads alright, I would appreciate it.

(Note that all of Spivak's functions are assumed to be $f: A \to \mathbb R$, where $A \subseteq \mathbb R$)

---

*Base Case*: Let $x=1$. Prove that the $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f$ exists at point $c$.

By assumption, $f^{(n)}(c)$ exists, which means there is some $D \in \mathbb R$ such that $f^{(n)}(c)=D$. Applying the definition of the $n$th derivative, we have:

$$f^{(n)}(c)=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(c+h)-f^{(n-1)}(c)}{h}=D$$

Implicit in the above syntax is the fact that the function $f^{(n-1)}$ must be *defined* at point $c$. If $f^{(n-1)}$ is defined at point $c$, then there is some $L \in \mathbb R$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(c)=L$. Therefore, the $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f$ at point $c$ equals $L$.

*Assume*: For any $x$ such that $1 \lt x \lt n$, let $f^{(n-x)}(c)$ exist.

*Prove for $x+1$*: Prove that $f^{(n-(x+1))}(c)=f^{(n-x-1)}(c)$ exists.

By assumption, the $(n-x)^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f$ exists at point $c$, which means that there is some $D' \in \mathbb R$ such that $f^{(n-x)}(c)=D'$. Applying the definition of the $(n-x)^{\text{th}}$ derivative, we have:

$$f^{(n-x)}(c)=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f^{(n-x-1)}(c+h)-f^{(n-x-1)}(c)}{h}=D'$$

Implicit in the above syntax is the fact that the function $f^{(n-x-1)}$ must be *defined* at point $c$. If $f^{(n-x-1)}$ is defined at point $c$, then there is some $L' \in \mathbb R$ such that $f^{(n-x-1)}(c)=L'$. Therefore, the $(n-x-1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f$ at point $c$ equals $L'$.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is differentiable and let $f'$ be its derivative. We can think about the second derivative of $f$ only if $f'$ is differentiable. So if $f^{(n)}$ exists means that all lower derivatives exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only refer to the second derivative of a function exists at a point $c$ if the first derivative exists at every point in some *neighbourhood* of $c$.  That comes from the definition of derivative.

But I would not say that this condition is a matter needing proof; it is more that the second derivative is meaningless without it.

In your proof you only concentrate on $c$ but equally implicit is that the prior derivative exists at all $c+h$ as well for small enough $h$.